# Add Startup and shutdown scripts to Local Group Policy using Powershell

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, group-policy

I am trying to automate adding startup and shutdown scripts to Local Group Policy (gpedit.msc). One solution is to write to registry directly as pointed out in http://ccm.net/faq/3358-execute-a-script-a-startup-and-shutdown. I'm looking for a way to do it via powershell script using the GroupPolicy module. I want to know if this is possible/anyone has succeeded in doing this?

UPDATE: After reading through msdn articles, I figured out that we can access domain group policy objects but the local group policy object (which contains the startup and shutdown scripts) is stored in registry. I am trying to find a way to access and edit this local GPO through powershell.

Comment: Homework question?  What's wrong with doing it by registry?  What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: not homework. I am looking to automate it using powershell. It would be deployed with a bunch of other scripts. I'm trying to run an exe with arguments during startup and shutdown. Kindly see edit.

Comment: What's wrong with doing it by editing the registry?  That's the easy, obvious, low-hanging fruit, and it works.  You can script registry editing in powershell you know.  "one solution is 'X', but I want to do it a different way that I don;t know how to do..."

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this on a workgroup machines, configure it manually. If they are part of a domain, do it via GPO. All the same options are avail in GPO that are avail in local policy.

[image]

Comment: Just an opinion so I will keep it short. I prefer always using GPOs as splitting it can lead to confusion later. It might not be possible but it's something I have found to be a best practice.